# How to download access using '.htaccess' files?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I am working on a website on which music will be sold. I want people to be able to only play and listen to the songs but not actually download them. To achieve this behaviour, I have limited the directory access using `.htaccess` password protection.

When users however want to listen to the song, it also asks for a password, and given the password, users can also download the content.

How do I make it so users can only listen to the music, but not download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When users are listening to the songs, they are already downloading it. Everything you access from the internet gets downloaded.

If you would prevent users from downloading your music they simply wouldn't be able to get the music and as a result wouldn't be able to listen to it.

Popular players like YouTube also download all the videos to your computer as you watch them, but it deletes them once you're done. (Actually they never even make it on your hard drive, they stay in RAM)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. HTTP doesn't work like that.

The data has to be downloaded in order for it to be played. There is no way for the server to distinguish between "Downloaded to a cache for playback" and "Downloaded for saving to a file the user knows about".

The closest you could some would be to implement some kind of streaming server that doesn't use HTTP (e.g. one that uses RTMP) but that would require something more complex than an Apache configuration and could still be bypassed by the end user.